# What exception type should be thrown when trying to add duplicate items to a collection?

Tags: c#, .net, exception, duplicates

Following code should throw exception to prevent adding duplicate collection item.

```
ICollection<T> collection = new List<T>();

public void Add(T item)
{
    if (collection.Contain(item))
    {
          throw new SomeExceptionType()
    }

    collection.Add(item);
}
```

What standard exception type is the most appropriate?

Comment: Closest specific exception I found was [DuplicateNameException](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.duplicatenameexception(v=vs.110).aspx) for databases ... which is just a bad idea for a `Collection`. Take home message: Anyone wanting more specific could _roll their own Exception_

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Well, `Dictionary<,>.Add()` throws `ArgumentException` if such key already exists, so I guess this could be a precedent.

Answer (score 14):

Linq uses two more exceptions **DuplicateNameException** and **DuplicateKeyException** you can use these if you are using system.data assembly.

Answer (score 6):

[ArgumentException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.argumentexception.aspx) would probably be the best. This is the exception thrown when an argument is invalid.

Answer (score 5):

I would use [`InvalidOperationException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.invalidoperationexception.aspx):

> The exception that is thrown when a
>   method call is invalid for the
>   object's current state.

Since the validity of the argument's value is contingent upon the state of the object (that is whether or not `collection.Contains(item)` is true) I think this is the best exception to use.

Make sure that you add a good message to the exception that makes it clear what the problem was to the caller.

Comment: IMHO, InvalidOperationException will confuse user because it used mostly to show unapropriate oparation sequence. For instance, reading from closed reader, etc.

Answer (score 3):

ArgumentException would be the proper exception (Dictionary uses that exception as well)

Answer (score 2):

I'd say `InvalidOperationException`, because it is not valid to add an object that's already in the collection

Comment: If it were a Dictionary this would be true, but it's not.

Comment: There are collections that don't allow duplicates, AND dictionaries that allow them... in the poster's case he clearly doesn't want duplicates, or why would he want to throw an exception ?

Comment: Sorry, I phrased that comment badly, I more meant to say that if the OP is using a collection that does allow duplicates, its not really an invalid operation. Its a "he doesn't consider this valid" thing. Also I'm not the one who downvoted this >_> I don't agree this is the best exception, but I don't think it would be wrong to use it.

Answer (score 1):

```
System.ArgumentException
```

Answer (score 1):

I would throw an ArgumentException.  That's what the generic `System.Collections.Generic.SortedList<>` does in its `Add` method.

From the .NET Framework 2.0 code:

```
    public void Add(TKey key, TValue value)
    {
        if (key == null)
        {
            System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentNullException(System.ExceptionArgument.key);
        }
        int num = Array.BinarySearch<TKey>(this.keys, 0, this._size, key, this.comparer);
        if (num >= 0)
        {
            System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentException(System.ExceptionResource.Argument_AddingDuplicate);
        }
        this.Insert(~num, key, value);
    }
```